# Getting nonsensical errors when running Android Application - "java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation..." RuntimeException

Tags: android, eclipse, compiler-errors, adt

I have a demo application that relies on a library we've developed. This was running fine until I just started randomly getting "Unresolved compilation problem" RuntimeException when I went to run the application. I had seen this before and usually a clean build fixes this, but that's no longer the case.

The errors that follow the "Unresolved compilation problem" are related to not being able to find packages it clearly show find:

```
AndroidRuntime(893):  The import java.util cannot be resolved
AndroidRuntime(893):  The import android cannot be resolved
```

When this happens the project will start to show up in error. Almost all the issues are around one of our Exception classes "not extending Throwable" despite the fact it extends 'Exception' (which of course extends Throwable).

I've done the following:

- Ensured depend projects are properly referenced
- Clean/build
- Deleted the work space and brought the projects back down through source control
- Deleted the ADT (with eclipse & SDK) and .android/ directories and re-installed

I feel like I'm running out of options here. Any ideas?

**Update:** I decided to recreate the library project and copy the source. This actually fixed the problem for a short while until I changed the 'targetSdkVersion' from 16 to 18. After this it stopped working. Changing it back to 16 did not make a difference.

Comment: Also, this is meta, but not being able to put the word "problem" in a title is a bit idiotic.

Comment: It is indeed meta.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110789/remove-blacklist-filter-for-problem.